# Why was this repair question put on hold?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

A relatively new user asked [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/135402/replacing-capacitor-from-unworking-tv-with-some-other-capatitors-which-has-not-t/135403#135402) about repairing a faulty capacitor on his TV but it was put on hold as off-topic due to a policy that ["repair" questions are considered off-topic](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/is-asking-on-how-to-fix-a-faulty-circuit-on-topic).

However, it doesn't appear to be an absolute rule that "repair" questions are off-topic -- the [top answer to the meta question on the policy](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2479/51760) says that the rule exists because they are *in general* too localized.

But this question has an underlying design question: how does one build an equivalent capacitance (here \$1500\mu\$F) out of capacitors that do not have the desired capacitance?

I think this is a useful question and is not too "localized". Should it simply be re-worded so that it is not about repairing a TV?

Answer (score 4):

From the reason:

> Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must [...] demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired.

This condition wasn't met.
It's still not met.

Comment: The underlying design question is about equivalent capacitance and component ratings somewhat like [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/103388/circuit-capacitance-question) and [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60159/can-i-use-a-4-7uf-50v-in-place-of-a-4-7uf-25v), neither of which were put on hold. Would the question be "on-topic" if it was re-worded to not mention the repair of a TV and instead discuss only the underlying design question?

Comment: The underlying design question is something that the O.P. didn't ask.  We probably have a canonical (or close to it) question about capacitor in series and parallel, somewhere.  [This one](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/103388/7036) is not a repair question.  [This one](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/60159/7036) deserves *off-topic→repair*.

Comment: Then why not close the question as DUPLICATE instead of off topic...