# Is specific circuit debugging questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a picture of a circuit that is leaking current from 4 double AA batteries. I wish to post a question regarding what procedure to use to debug the circuit to find the current leak. Is this question on topic? If not, how can I frame the question to be on topic? Thanks.

Comment: Don't sweat the whole on/off topic thing. If you haven't already, I'd recommend you frame your question in the form of expected vs actual behavior, along with the schematic (if available). Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

It's good that you have asked on meta first.  Here's the disposition towards troubleshooting questions.

> Questions on the repair<sup>1</sup> of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design<sup>2</sup> of the device being repaired. See also: [Is asking on how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/is-asking-on-how-to-fix-a-faulty-circuit-on-topic)

<sup>1</sup> incl. troubleshooting
<sup>2</sup> this boils down to having the schematic

*p.s.*  Troubleshooting usually requires dialog and brainstorming.  StackExchange Q&A format is good for wiki-style information, but the Q&A format is not the most graceful for dealing with troubleshooting requests.