# Are "check my working" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I am working on a permanent lighting array for my bicycle.  I'm not an electrics or electronics person, but this is a real plan and I intend to complete it.

I have current and voltage measurements, wire gauges/lengths, and specs of my battery source.

Is it on-topic for this site to lay all that data out and check my working and calculations ?

---

Possibly related [Is specific circuit debugging questions on topic?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5365/is-specific-circuit-debugging-questions-on-topic) but that's about a circuit - my question is simpler because there is no circuit, and the schematic would be quite simple.

Comment: Consider pre-discussing it in [our EE.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).  Give it a shot (or two) in the chat first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for asking first.

In general, we discourage broad, open-ended design review questions on EE.SE, because the answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow design review questions in which you explain your choices and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts. To get a better feel of what is or is not acceptable, search for "design review" here on meta.

Comment: Thank you.  On Bicycles we often suggest these "less-structured" questions go on the [chat] which is more ephemeral.  Will try that.

Comment: @Crig: Sending bicycle questions to EE chat makes no sense.

Comment: @OlinLathrop its a question about a lighting circuit, wire dimensions, voltage drop, and battery duration and total lifespan.  Circuit just happens to be on a bike.  I have confirmed my calculations to within 20% by using the age-old method of "throw it together and see what happens"

Answer (score 3):

Battery capacity vs. lifespan was discussed here many times ([example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/329217/battery-capacity-and-duration)), and so was wire gauge vs. voltage drop ([example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/263690/determining-suitable-wire-gauge-for-led-strips-voltage-drop)). If your question boils down to repeating the same calculations for your set of numbers, it will likely not be received well.

If you've done your own calculations, built your circuit, and observed a discrepancy you cannot explain, that would make a much better question.