# "Repair" tag exists, but repair is off-topic

Tags: discussion

In the comments to [Unwinding a brushed (AC, 120v 60hz) motor to the tune of one turn, what for to gain length](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/286264/unwinding-a-brushed-ac-120v-60hz-motor-to-the-tune-of-one-turn-what-for-to-g?noredirect=1#comment653490_286264)  the submitter says:

> "repair" was a keyword in the system so i guess i assumed this is something that is asked here.

Should repair be removed from the tags?

Comment: This had been already brought up (among other things) in [this thread](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6037/meta-tags-cleanup#comment14185_6037).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meta-tags cleanup?](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6037/meta-tags-cleanup)

Answer (score 5):

Repair questions *are* on-topic, but they must meet a minimum threshold. See the close reason:

> Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other
>   devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a
>   good understanding of the underlying design of the device being
>   repaired. See also: [Is asking on how to fix a faulty circuit on
>   topic](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/is-asking-on-how-to-fix-a-faulty-circuit-on-topic)?