# Should we really have a DIY tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup

We have a tag [diy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy) which doesn't seem on-topic, given the tag wiki:

> Do It Yourself. Build, modify, repair something without the aid of trained professionals.

This doesn't seem to fit the site, since we require that repair questions are backed with details and at least some electronics knowledge to perform measurements, provide schematics etc. [Is asking on how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/is-asking-on-how-to-fix-a-faulty-circuit-on-topic)

Such questions should generally be closed and https://diy.stackexchange.com is a more suitable site for them.

So it seems that this tag might encourage bad questions. Should it be removed?

Answer (score 18):

In the description, there is "repair", but also "build, modify". And even if we just consider "repair", you can "provide details and have some electronic knowledge to perform measurements, provide schematics etc." without being a "trained professional". For example, I don't consider myself a trained professional, but I know I could ask an acceptable repair question (once the [repair guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/repair-guidelines-where-are-they-and-where-should-they-be) are clarified, though... what a mess...).

**However**, this tag should probably be killed, indeed. It looks like a [meta-tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) (like "beginner" or "example", or something like that), and doesn't really add value to the classification. In particular, it wouldn't work if a question had only this tag alone.

So let's get rid of it, but not for the reason you mentioned.

---

**Edit**: Had a closer look at the questions. In most cases, [diy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy) doesn't add any information. In some cases, however, it highlights specific questions where OP wants to achieve, by themselves, manufacturing steps that are usually made in factory houses, or build their own component parts. Examples:

- [Custom/DIY Metal-Core PCB?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/308674/custom-diy-metal-core-pcb)
- [Soldering BGA components DIY](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/135659/soldering-bga-components-diy)
- [Techniques for building 'Bed of Nails' testing board](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/358738/techniques-for-building-bed-of-nails-testing-board)
- [Would it be possible to make a solid state transistor by hand?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171704/would-it-be-possible-to-make-a-solid-state-transistor-by-hand)
- [Building homemade low inductance capacitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/344282/building-homemade-low-inductance-capacitor)
- [2D DIY capacitive panel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/358718/2d-diy-capacitive-panel)

I think this may be interesting to keep this subset of questions appropriately identified by a specific tag ([diy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy) may be a bit too broad and unspecific, though... Maybe "homemade", with an appropriate tag description?).

Comment: I agree, it is a meta tag. "Trained professional" in this context might just mean that you can handle a multimeter and solder iron, and that you have some general clue about how to handle electronics (remove supply, check polarity, consider ESD etc). It doesn't have to mean an EE degree.

Comment: Almost exactly my position. As I always remind people here, until we split the site, we welcome beginners, hackers and makers with no formal EE training or education. These people often "hack" things and EE.SE is the best place to ask for guidance, especially when safety is at stake. This is more so for electrical systems: home improvement site is the right place only if the asker wants hand-holding and doesn't want/need deep understanding of what he is doing. Whatever the hack, if someone wants to understand *why* it has do do this and that, this is the right place to ask, IMO.

Comment: BTW, I agree the help section is far from clear on many topics.

Comment: Moreover, the tag DIY is indeed useless. Even if not considered meta (which I agree it is somewhat), it is exceedingly broad anyway, and doesn't help searching at all. BURNINATE IT! :-D

Comment: @LorenzoDonati It is 149 posts so we'd need help from a moderator, I believe.