# Change off-topic close reason "Appliance" repair

Tags: feature-request

I don't like the usage of the word **appliance** in the off-topic close reason for poor repair questions:

> "Questions on appliance repair are off-topic unless they involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired."

According to Merriam Webster's dictionary: An appliance is:

> "a machine (such as a stove, microwave, or dishwasher) that is powered by electricity and that is used in people's houses to perform a particular job"

[A recent question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/91952/2028) about how to unplug cables on a computer motherboard was closed for this reason. The problem is, it's not really an appliance, and I envision the OP scratching his or her head wondering how we categorize these things.

Instead, I'd like to see a close reason for poor repair questions worded something like:

> "Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired."

Or the short version:

> "Questions on electronics *repair* must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired.

[Zebonaut's meta question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/684/2028) about improving repair questions is a great reference.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Write up the text in an answer so we can vote on it. Neither of your suggestions should hita character limit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Proposed new close reason:

> Questions on the **repair** of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired. See also: [Is asking on how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/is-asking-on-how-to-fix-a-faulty-circuit-on-topic)

Comment: This is now one of the off-topic close reasons. Go ahead and accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: @W5VO Thanks for your input and support on the proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Proposed new close reason (shorter version):

> "Questions on electronics repair must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired."