# Would questions about peripherals asking in user perspective be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope

As a normal user, sometimes my [peripherals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peripheral) don't work as expected. Here is the question I want to ask:

> I have a PS3 controller, but my computer doesn't recognize it when plugged in for the first time for a couple of hours or more not using it. However it recognize the controller after replugging it. Since in theory it shouldn't be like that, I wonder what is happening.

It's on-topic on Super User, but seems to be poor-received (example: [What makes keyboard suddenly stop working when BIOS is loading?](https://superuser.comhttps://superuser.com/q/1167862/301042)). There is a [peripheral](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peripheral) tag on this site, but the questions there seems to have more technical knowledge than I have. From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it is not clear that this kind of question explicitly be on-topic, but IMO it doesn't fall on the off-topics:

> This site is for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts. We ask and answer questions about electrical and electronics engineering topics, which include electronics, physical computing, and those working with microcontrollers, Arduinos and embedded systems. We feel the best Electronics Design questions have a schematic, links to pertinent datasheets or some source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific electronics design problem
> - the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces
> - a communication scheme
> - the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
> - consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, except when designing these products or modifying their electronics for other uses
> - Programming software for a PC

Would question asking for reasons and fixes on peripherals be on-topic here? If yes, will it be well-received?

Comment: In EE we often think of a peripheral as a circuit integrated into a microcontroller which runs more or less independent of the processing core. Like a UART or RTC or something like that. We should probably give that tag a correct wiki entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions about use are off-topic.

> Questions on the *use* of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics *design*.

Questions about repair are off-topic.

> Questions on the **repair** of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired. See also: [Is asking on how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/is-asking-on-how-to-fix-a-faulty-circuit-on-topic)

Comment: Why aren't those paragraph in the [help/on-topic]?

Comment: @Ooker That is a very good question. They should be, because that's the reason we give when closing a question.

Comment: @pipe I've opened a question regarding this: [Put close reasons on the help page](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6324/66087)

Comment: @Nick, would this be on-topic? "What would cause a peripheral only be recognized at the second time being plugged in computer?"

Comment: @Ooker  The sort answer to that question is "that's how the driver was designed".  It's a software question.

Comment: @NickAlexeev there is no driver required for the device. How about changing the question to *send the signal*?

Comment: Are you designing this peripheral?  Or, is this something you are using?

Comment: @NickAlexeev no, just a tool I bought to use. I just happen to isolate the problem. I think the circuit is available on the internet, and I want to learn more about electronics.

Comment: You can take a question like that to our [EE.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).  Questions about electronics *use* are off-topic in the main EE.SE board.